# className statement not re-rending when useState is set

Tags: reactjs, rxjs

When I click a "Thread"/button `handleClick` get's called and the `currentIndex` is updated/set which triggers the button's `className` ternary statement to execute as `true`. However, as there are many `<li>` elements, the other elements do not re-render `className` to the `false` statement. `currentIndex` should not == `thread.id` for those elements.

**ThreadItem component**

```
import { useState } from 'react'

const ThreadItem = ({ thread, changeThread }) => {

    const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState('')

    // On thread click
    const handleClick = (threadId) => {
        setCurrentIndex(threadId)
    }

    return (
        <li className="chat-item">
            <form onSubmit={changeThread}>
                <button className={currentIndex == thread.id ? 'side-menu-links-focus threads' : 'side-menu-links threads'} onClick={() => handleClick(thread.id)}>{`#${thread.threadType}`}</button>
            </form>
        </li>
    )
}

export default ThreadItem
```

**Parent ThreadList component**

```
import ThreadItem from './ThreadItem'

const ThreadList = ({ threads, changeThread }) => {

    return (
        <ul className='chat-list'>
            {threads.map((thread) => (
                <ThreadItem
                    key={thread.id}
                    thread={thread}
                    changeThread={changeThread}
                />
            ))}
        </ul>
    )
}

export default ThreadList
```

Comment: Where are the many `<li>` elements? This component only renders one. Is there additional code you need to share?

Comment: @Benjamin I added the ThreadList component. For each thread, a ThreadItem component is rendered.

Comment: You need to provide a fully reproducible example.

Comment: Am I missing something or should button be `<button type="submit">` to invoke `changeThread`?

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos I added `type="submit"` but it works without. Apparently default type is `submit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to click a button, and have a single `ThreadItem` to change `className`.

The problem I see is that you have added `useState` to every `ThreadItem`. Instead, you should move the state above to the `ThreadList` component.

This way, there is only one instance of state for the entire list of items. Simply pass the `active` prop and an `onClick` handler to each `ThreadItem`.

#### ThreadList

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ThreadItem from './ThreadItem';

const ThreadList = ({ threads, changeThread }) => {
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState('');

  // On thread click
  const handleClick = (threadId) => {
    setCurrentIndex(threadId);
  };

  return (
    <ul className="chat-list">
      {threads.map((thread) => (
        <ThreadItem
          key={thread.id}
          thread={thread}
          changeThread={changeThread}
          isActive={currentIndex === thread.id}
          onClick={() => handleClick(thread.id)}
        />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default ThreadList;
```

#### ThreadItem

```js
import React from 'react';

const ThreadItem = ({ thread, changeThread, isActive, onClick }) => {
  return (
    <li className="chat-item">
      <form onSubmit={changeThread}>
        <button
          className={isActive ? 'side-menu-links-focus threads' : 'side-menu-links threads'}
          onClick={onClick}
        >{`#${thread.threadType}`}</button>
      </form>
    </li>
  );
};

export default ThreadItem;
```